# Finding Cumulative Probability Distribution with inequality

Tags: probability

I have been having difficulty figuring out the cumulative distribution, especially the ones where it says the bounds for x or y are given like xy and not numbers. I am completely stuck on this problem given below. The answer is supposed to be 0.50. I tried a couple of different ways but my answer is not 0.50.
Any help is much appreciated.

***Question :***
Probability Density function is given as follows:

$f(x,y) = 3x, \quad 0 \le y \le x \le 1$

$f(x,y) = 0, elsewhere $

Find $P(Y\le X/2)$

My solution: $$\int_0^\frac{x}{2}\int_y^13x\,dx\,dy$$
(since $\quad 0\le y \le x/2 $, $\quad y \le x \le 1$ ) 
However, this approach does not give me 0.50 which is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition,

$\mathbb{P}(Y\leq X/2)=\mathbb{P}((X,Y)\in B)=\iint_B f(x,y) dxdy$

where $B=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: y\leq x/2\}$.

Now, for solve this integral, parametrize the region $B$.

Comment: I tried to do that. However, I think I am missing something and not able to identify the correct region. The answer I am getting is a function of x, whereas the correct answer is 0.5

Comment: the integral is a number, can't depend of any variable. Try with $0<y<1$ and $2y<x<1$

Comment: As Martin suggested, the resulting integral would be:
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x/2}3x\,\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x
$$
So the overall result is not a function of $x$.

Comment: Thanks Andrea & Martin. The resulting integral yields an answer of 0.50 which is correct. Can you please explain how did you come up with the resulting integral from 0<y<1 and 2y<x<1? It seems like you reversed the limits for dy and dx.